# what is the type of Array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, casting

I want to write a method to judge if there isNullOrEmpty of a ICollection instance, for example:

```
public static bool IsCollectionNullOrEmpty<T>(ICollection<T> instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (instance.GetType() == typeof(Array))
        {
            return new List<T>(instance).Count <= 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return instance.Count <= 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, I dont know how to get the type of instance if is Like T[], Please help me if there is an example will be great, Thanks

Comment: `return instance == null || instance.Count == 0;` that's all you need I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do that instead is taking in an IEnumerable (which is more generic than ICollection since ICollection implements IEnumerable) and simply checking it for null and else returning Any() from linq's operators

```
public static bool IsCollectionNullOrEmpty<T>(IEnumerable<T> instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return !instance.Any();
}
```

Or as others mentioned if you want to stick to ICollection then there's no need to check for arrays and all that, you take in an ICollection, and ICollection has a count member so you can use count directly, no need to pass an array to a new list constructor to access a count property.

The reason you can't just do .Count on a random array is because the implementation is hidden but since in this context your parameter isn't explcitely an array but an ICollection you can just call .Count on it (array has a .Count method, it's just hidden but it has to have it since it implements ICollection)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx

This is why :

```
((ICollection)(new int[] { 0 })).Count; //  this compiles
(new int[] { 0 }).Count; // this doesn't, althought it's the same object
```

So if you really want to write it like you did you could simplify it as such :

```
public static bool IsCollectionNullOrEmpty<T>(ICollection<T> instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return instance.Count <= 0; // this does the exact same thing as your previous else block except it's massively simpler and doesn't create a new list
}
```

Note that this really doesn't sound like a useful method at all (i'd drop it personally) since it barely adds any value over the Any operator so i'd just check for null if needed and then call any without creating a custom method just for that.

Instead of using this method i'd just do the following everytime i have a collection i need to check:

```
if(mycollection == null || (!mycollection.Any())
```

Comment: Thx！ I just want to write a method instead of checking null and Empty

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use `GetType().IsArray` but that limits you to pure array types. A more general solution would be to check it's `Count` property since you already know it's an `ICollection<T>`.  That will work for arrays as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need such strange cast as array already implements `ICollection<T>`:

```
public static bool IsCollectionNullOrEmpty<T>(this ICollection<T> instance)
{
       return instance == null ? true : instance.Count == 0;
}
```

Added `this` to allow invoking as extension method too:

```
var isEmpty = (new int[0]).IsCollectionNullOrEmpty();
```

Comment: You don't need a ternary operator to do that, just or the result.

Comment: @Phill indeed. Conditional operator is a bit close to OP syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if(instance.GetType() == typeof (T[]))
```